# Storing results in a list in PySpark session

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am running the following lines in a PySpark session

```
y = sns.histplot(data=df, x="height", hue='gender', alpha=0.5, multiple="dodge", stat="percent")

female = []
male = []
for f,m in zip(y.containers[0], y.containers[1]):
    female.append(f.get_height())
    male.append(m.get_height())

print(female)
print(male)

female_per = ['{:.2f}%'.format(x/sum(female)*100) for x in female]
male_per = ['{:.2f}%'.format(x/sum(male)*100) for x in male]
print(female_per)
print(male_per)

y.bar_label(y.containers[0], labels=female_per)
y.bar_label(y.containers[1], labels=male_per)

# y.bar_label(y.containers[0])
# y.bar_label(y.containers[1])

plt.show()
```

However, I am encountering the error below
[image: example]

Any hints on the potential issue and solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the type of `df`?  Maybe you should convert it from Spark-dataframe to pandas-dataframe?

Comment: It's a already a pandas dataframe

Comment: I don't have much experience with pyspark, so I can't help you much, but is there any environmental impact? My environment was created with pandas 1.3.5, matplotlib 3.5.1, seaborn 0.11.2.

Comment: @r-beginners thanks so much for your feedback. I sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: Any chance you are shadowing the built-in `sum` with the `sum` from pyspark.sql.functions? If you do `print(sum.__module__)` what do you get?

Comment: @ScootCork thanks so much for the hint. That was the problem. I was using ```from pyspark.sql.functions import * ```